# How do I add values to a list stored as a dictionary value?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have an empty dictionary, and need to pull industry info base on ticker symbols. I would then like to add all tickers under the same industry in a list with the industry as the key.

For example, the end would look something like the below:

```
{'technology': ['AAPL', 'ADBE'], 'Consumer Cyclical': ['TSLA', 'UA']}
```

Here is what I've been working on with no success:

```
import yfinance as yf

tickers = ['AAPL', 'ADBE', 'AMD', 'AMAT', 'AMZN', 'ANF',
                    'APA', 'BA', 'BABA', 'BBY', 'BIDU', 'BMY', 'BRX', 'BZUN',
                    'C', 'CAT', 'CLF', 'CMCSA', 'CMG', 'COST', 'CRM', 'CVX',
                    'DE', 'EBAY', 'FB', 'FCX', 'FDX', 'FSLR', 
                    'GILD', 'GM', 'GME', 'GOOG','GPRO', 'GS',  'HAL', 'HD',
                    'HIG', 'HON', 'IBM', 'JCPB', 'JD', 'JPM', 'LULU', 'LYG', 
                    'MA', 'MCD', 'MDT', 'MS', 'MSFT','MU', 'NEM', 'NFLX',
                    'NKE','PBR', 'QCOM', 'SLB', 'SNAP', 'SPG', 'TSLA', 'TWTR',
                    'TXN', 'UA', 'UAL', 'V', 'VZ' 'X', 'XLNX', 'ZM']
sector_dict = dict()
for ticker in tickers:
    try:
        sector = yf.Ticker(ticker).info['sector']
        sector_dict[sector].update(ticker)


    except:
        sector_dict.update({'no sector':[ticker]})
```

The below just gives me an empty dictionary.  Does anybody see where the issue is?

Comment: why do you define `tickers = ['AAPL', ..` if you dont use it?

Comment: what is `sky_view_tickers ` and what is `sector`?

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  First, you need only one or two tickers to illustrate the problem.  Don't call an external package; simply hard-code the value of `sector`.  That will isolate the problem.

Comment: @Jordan. See my answer. I am not familiar with this API but I think this is the direction to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the information you need is returned from the API call - the code below may work for you.

```
import yfinance as yf
from collections import defaultdict
tickers = ['AAPL','ADBE']
sector_dict = defaultdict(list)
for ticker in tickers:
  try: 
    sector_dict[yf.Ticker(ticker).info['sector']].append(ticker)
  except Exception as e:
    print(f'Failed to get ticker info for {ticker}')
print(sector_dict)
```

output

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'Technology': ['AAPL', 'ADBE']})
```

Comment: Thank you.  That also gave me an empty dict.

Comment: Interesting.. See my answer. As you can see I get a non empty dict. Give it a try

Comment: Some tickers may not pull anything in my original list.  Maybe that's what's throwing an error.  It's so big that I'm not sure which one's they are.

Comment: I have updated the code with two tickers and produce the exact output you are looking for. Maybe some of the tickers in you list are invalid..

Comment: @Jordan Use my code and find the problematic tickers (using try/except)

Answer (score 1):

You should always avoid catch-all exceptions.

Your original example was masking the fact that `update` isn't a list method.
When you subscript a python dictionary like `sector_dict[ticker]`, we're now talking about the value associated with the `ticker` key. In this case a list.

Also update isn't used like that, so I think it was masking a second error. It's usage is to update a dictionary with another dictionary or an iterable. Not to update an existing entry.

Finally, the `try` clause should be as small as possible, in order to be sure where the error is coming from or at least you can guarantee there won't be conflicting exceptions such as this case.

I think that's why your list is returning with only the last ticker in my previous solution, as `yf.Ticker` causes a `KeyError` and the `KeyError` exception gets called instead of the last one.

Here's how I'd do it:

```
sector_dict = {'no sector':[]}
for ticker in tickers:
    try:
        sector = yf.Ticker(ticker).info['sector']    
    except KeyError:
        sector_dict['no sector'].append(ticker)
    try:
        sector_dict[sector].append(ticker)
    except KeyError:
        sector_dict[sector] = [ticker]
```

Comment: Thank you.  The original list is bigger and multiple tickers will be with these sectors.  This solution seems to only give the last ticker to be ran through for each sector.

Comment: I'm sorry I rushed in for an answer, I'll update with a better solution and explanation